# Use a React/Remix app to essentially patch an older application created in .NET

Tags: mysql, reactjs, .net, iis, remix.run

Like the title states, I'm looking to create an app to create a forgot password flow for an older app. The app is 90% complete, just working on building out the reset password form/page along with tokens and expires for the tokens. The app uses Remix/Prisma/MongoDB/Netlify.

The OLD app is built on .NET/mySQL/IIS and is hosted on AWS/EC2 instance. Is it possible to GET/POST to the mySQL DB from an outside app running on a subdomain for the application? If so, very high level, what do we need to do to make this work?

We have full access to the system and happy to provide any fruther information. For context, the old app is compiled with no chance of retrieving the uncompiled codebase hence this approach.

Comment: Mysql does not have a http endpoint, you need code that can directly access it.

Comment: .NET is rather easy to reverse engineer, so I wonder why "the old app is compiled with no chance of retrieving the uncompiled codebase hence this approach".

Comment: b/c the old uncompiled codebase has been lost, never to be found again my friend. We could of course reverse engineer and I feel like "easy" is relative. I would much rather move away to a modern framework and may just do that.  Maybe launching the new app on IIS is the way to go.